# <c:forEach paramValues> does not output anything

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have  these checkboxes in a form:

```
Ethnicity (Check all that apply):<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" value="Caucasian">Caucasian<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" value="Asian">Asian<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" value="Hispanic">Hispanic<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" value="African American">African American<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" value="Pacific Islander">Pacific Islander<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" value="Native American">Native American<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ethnicity" value="Prefer not to answer">Prefer not to answer<br><br>
```

When the form is submitted I go to another page, called echo.jsp.  Inside echo.jsp all I want to do is echo back everything that was submitted.

However, this code prints absolutely nothing:

```
<c:forEach items="${paramValues.ethnicity}" var="item">
       <c:out value="${item}" /> <br>
</c:forEach>
```

While this code prints out exactly what was checked...

```
<%
    String select[] = request.getParameterValues("ethnicity"); 
    if (select != null && select.length != 0) {
        out.println("You have selected: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
             out.println(select[i]); 
        }
     }
%>
```

Am I missing something?  Why doesnt the JSTL foreach loop work with paramValues?

I should be noted, this is only a small portion of the form.  I have lots of other form items like first name, last name, email, etc....

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  I am a jsp/jstl newbie and didnt know I needed this in my page:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

I realized there must be something really basic going on because none of the jstl tags I was using worked.